# Function to fire on checkbox change or on jQuery slider.slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to join two ajax calls into one. One fires on a checkbox change in the form, and the other fires when the jQuery slider "slides". I would like to combine the two.

I was thinking of using a .bind(), but I need to use more than one jQuery selector, and more than one event.

The two jQuery selectors would be:

1. $("input[type=checkbox]")
2. $( "#pay_range" ).slider

The two different events would be, respectively

1. .click()
2. .slide()

Obviously, the different event listeners have to go with the correct jQuery selectors.

the js for the checkboxes:

```
    // when a checkbox is clicked
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

    // remove the original results
    $('#original_results').css("display", "none");

    // which filter section does it belong to
    var filter_section = $(this).attr('name');

    // should it be filtered out or left in
    var remove = $(this).prop('checked');

    // if needs to be filtered
    if (!remove)
    {
        // add it to our filter list for the specified section
        filters[filter_section].push(this.value);
    }
    else
    {
        // take it off the list for the specified section
        var index = filters[filter_section].indexOf(this.value);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            filters[filter_section].splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/results/search_filter',
        //url: url,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Display a loading message while waiting for the ajax call to complete
            $('#filter_updating').html("Filtering your search...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //inject the results
            $('#search_results').html(response);
        },

        data: { filters: filters, criteria: criteria }
    }); // end ajax setup

});
```

the js for the slider:

```
$(function() {
$( "#pay_range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: pay_min,
    max: pay_max,
    values: [ pay_min, pay_max ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#filter_by_pay" ).html( "Pay Range: ¥" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - ¥" + ui.values[ 1 ] ).css("color", "black");
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/results/search_filter',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //Display a loading message while waiting for the ajax call to complete
                $('#filter_updating').html("Filtering your search...");
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //inject the results
                $('#search_results').html(response);
            },

            data: { min: ui.values[0], max: ui.values[1] }

        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: what does `combine the two` mean? Combine code into one `doAjax` function to be used in both places? or bind events together? If latter would need a lot more understanding of relation between checkboxes and slider

Comment: the goal is to make one ajax call that includes the data from both the slider and the checkboxes -- basically any solution that lets me write "data: { min: ui.values[0], max: ui.values[1], filters: filters, criteria: criteria }"

Comment: @charlietfl also, the checkboxes and the slider have no relationship per se, I just need the information from both of them at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify down to one function:

```
 function doAjax() {
    var ranges = $('#pay_range').slider('values')
    var data = {
      min: ranges[0],
      max: ranges[1],
      filters: filters,
      criteria: criteria
    }
    /* show loading*/
    $.post('ajaxData.html',data,function(response){         
     $('#search_results').html(response);
    })
  }
```

Then for slider:

```
$("#pay_range").slider({
      range: true,
      min: pay_min,
      max: pay_max,
      values: [pay_min, pay_max],
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        doAjax();
      }
    });
```

Do same thing in checkbox handler after you adjust filters

Your code doesn't show where `citeria` comes from

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OMSbMozjvAyGROQcNiFi?p=preview)**</kbd>